# How can I match all occurrences of a phrase not tagged with desired LaTeX tag?

Tags: regex, linux, unix, latex

## Purpose

Find all occurences of "Bernie Sanders" that have not been tagged with `\senator{` `}`. I want to list matches with `grep` for visual inspection. Then I'd like to fix up all files recursively with a single command (e.g. `sed`, which does not support non-greedy regex).

## Example File

```
Bernie Sanders
\senator{Bernie Sanders}
The senator of Vermont is \senator{Bernie Sanders}.
A \texttt{senator of Vermont} is Bernie Sanders.
A senator of Vermont is \textit{Bernie Sanders}.
\textit{Bernie Sanders} is a senator of Vermont.
Is this the same Bernie Sanders?
Is Bernie Sanders a good senator?
Will we ever see a \textbf{President Bernie Sanders}?
```

## Problem

The regular expression must not "accidentally" interfer with other commands

An attempt:
`\[^senator]*{Bernie Sanders`

I am not sure how to exclude senator, yet include spaces, and other commands before Bernie Sanders.

Start

- may be proceeded by a space
- not proceeded by \senator{
- may be first thing on a line

End

- may end with space, colon, semicolon, question mark, comma, parenthesis, bracket (if within another command), full stop/period

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
(?<!\\senator{)Bernie Sanders(?!\s*})
```

You can use this with `grep -P`.`Lookarounds` will make sure it is not wrapped in `senator` tag.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/vV1wW6/7

Comment: After running ` grep -Prin '(?<!\\senator{)Bernie Sanders(?!\s*})'` I get an error: `grep: invalid UTF-8 byte sequence in input`.

Comment: @macmadness86 `grep` only works on `UTF-8`.YOu might have to convert text to first `UTF-8` using `iconv -f UTF-16 -t UTF-8 myfile > temporary_file`

Comment: I was trying to implement this reex in python (for fun), because of the link you posted (and because I like python). Something came to mind. You do not match `\textit{Bernie Sanders}`.

Answer (score 1):

This will only match if the prefix \senator is absent

```
(?<!\\senator\{)Bernie\sSanders
```

Comment: Thank you for your time, however you did not specific what version of REGEX that is intended for or the tool (that I could use to figure out which version of the language you mean).  basic or extended REGEX? `https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression`

Comment: It's just basic REGEX. If the files can be opened in notepad++ you can use it to regex replace in multiple files with a single click.

Comment: `sed` does not support non-greedy operators. As alluded to in the question, I am on a unix system. Thanks for another option, however.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution would be to use a perl script. The following one-liner is working on your example (it uss one of the previous regexp):

```
perl -pe 's/(?<!\\senator{)Bernie\sSanders/The New Bernie Sanders/g' input.tex > output.tex
```

Basically it replaces any match of the regexp expression in the file `input.tex` by the string "The New Bernie Sanders". The result is printed in `output.tex`.

Furthermore, this script can be included in a bash script to process several files:

```
#!/bin/bash    
for i in {1..3}
do
    perl -pe 's/(?<!\\senator{)Bernie\sSanders/The New Bernie Sanders/g' input$i.tex > output$i.tex
done
```

This script processes the files `input1.tex`, `input2.tex`, `input3.tex` and prints the files `output1.tex`, `output2.tex`, `output2.tex`.

(the loop is very basic but my point was simply to show that the one-liner could easily be included in a bash script).

Answer (score 0):

A solution with `grep` (underlying assumptions: \senator{Bernie Sanders} occurs in one line; there aren't good and bad hits in the same line)

```
grep "Bernie Sanders" input.tex |  grep -v -e '\\senator{Bernie Sanders}'
```